# React hooks: maximum depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I a functional component in React, and when I use useState hook to set a value in the return, I am getting an error about Maximum update depth exceeded.

Here is the code:

```
const TaskDetail = (props) => {
    const [selectedOperatorForTime, setSelectedOperatorForTime] = useState({})
    return (
       <div >  
            <Query query={GET_API_VAL}>
              {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                  let operatorList = {key1: data.value1, key2: data.value2}

                  setSelectedOperatorForTime(operatorList);
       {//rest of the code}
```

I get the following error

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I tried putting the setState in a separate function instead of having it directly in the return, but I am still seeing the same error. Any guidance? I am using Apollo client (which is what the Query component is for. Unsure how I am causing this to be called repeatedly.

I tried replacing the operatorList with a string, and it works fine. So it seems to be an issue with an object. Anyone experienced this?

Comment: have you tried using useEffect?

Comment: @Xzeta I just tried but unable to get it working. And don't think I can update the state in useEffect? Thoughts?

Comment: Well it makes sense, you're changing your state in return (render). Why do you need to set your selectedOperatorForTime there?

Comment: I think we're missing some context in code but you can set your state in a `useEffect` as mentioned. Where do you get this value1 and value2 variables?

Comment: Thanks! The reason I am setting it in render is because of the value I receive from the Apollo graphql Query component. I need that value to set the state with. What would be a way to do that? I tried creating a function but that didn't solve it either.

Comment: Yes, useEffect is the answer here because updating state during a render cycle will trigger another render, etc.. you need a way to conditionally update state so it isn't updated each cycle. I agree with @IoannisPotouridis about missing context, if you could provide more (or all) of the component code we could perhaps see where a refactor could be made to improve performance.

Comment: Could a different approach for `Query` execution help? If `Query` is from `apollo`, you could use the hook instead.

Comment: I dont know the full context of your code, but why do you need to set operatorList in state, why not just use it directly in the JSX inside of <Query /> ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using react hooks anyway, you might as well use hooks for apollo-react documented [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/).

Instead of using the `Query` component in your JSX, you'd use `useQuery` at the top of your component like so:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_API_VAL);
```

This would possibly also remove the need for a seperate `useState` since it always contains the current data.

Your specific example, with no other changes, would look something like this:

```
const TaskDetail = (props) => {
    const [selectedOperatorForTime, setSelectedOperatorForTime] = useState({});
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_API_VAL);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Set selectedOperatorForTime whenever the data changes
        let operatorList = {key1: data.value1, key2: data.value2};
        setSelectedOperatorForTime(operatorList);
    }, [data]);

    return (
       <div >
       {//rest of the code}
```